# Using high voltage to serve pages behind ssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, high-voltage

I am using high voltage to serve about page. The path that is generated doesn't use https.
How do i use high voltage to server pages behind https?

[High Voltage Gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage)

Comment: Could you refer to high voltage? What is it?

Comment: its a rails engine to serve static pages.

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i got the answer for this.

```
page_url(:about, :protocol => "https")
```